# how to force column dtype prior to loading data with django ORM

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, django-orm

We are using pandas (v0.25.3) to run analysis and data manipulation from large data sets from our postgres database accessed via the Django ORM (django v2.2.6).

The situation we have is that the table we are importing to a DataFrame includes a foreign key ID column which is stored as a models.BigIntegerField. This foreign key field is typically a large number but can also be null in those rows where the foreign key is not set.

When we import the list of records from the Django query set into a new pandas DataFrame, pandas sets the dtype of the ID column to np.float64 since the data includes some null values. But, for those rows where the ID is not null, the conversion from BigInteger to np.float64 causes the least significant digits to change such that if we subsequently try to re-cast the column dtype to np.int64 (using DataFrame.astype()), we end up with a different value.

The following a simplified example of the problem we are seeing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = [{'id': 144123525091332019}, {'id': None}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
Out[6]: 
             id
0  1.441235e+17
1           NaN
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.astype({'id': np.int64})
Out[8]: 
                   id
0  144123525091332032
1                   0
```

Notice that as a result of the conversion from big integer to np.float64 and back to np.int64, the value in the id column of the first row has changed. The id value used in the example above was taken directly from a real occurrence in our system.

What is the recommended way to avoid the type conversion from int to float while importing the data to pandas so that we can stop the id value from changing on us?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While we continue looking for a better solution, we are resorting the brute force solution of looping through the QuerySet and changing all the None values to 0 prior to constructing the DataFrame. This causes pandas to assign the Int64 type to the column and avoids the casting to float.

```
for tgt in target_performance_set:
    if tgt['gv_target_id'] is None:
        tgt['gv_target_id'] = 0
```

It's ugly but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with None in the id column.  Numpy does not have NaN for integers.

So when converting between int64 and float64 you get a conversion error.  This shows it

```
 a = np.int64(144123525091332019)
 print(a)
 b = np.float64(a)
 print(b)
 c = np.int64(b)
 print(c)
```

which gives

```
144123525091332019
1.4412352509133203e+17
144123525091332032
```

so we need to avoid the conversion.  Now np.NaN is of type float64 and np.NaN is not of type int at all. But in pandas this has been solved and requires the use of extension dtype Int64 (capitalized), rather than the default dtype int64 (lowercase).

However, there is a problem with None and the conversion

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = [{'id': 144123525091332019}, {'id': 0}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,dtype='Int64') # here we are saying that use the int with NA
print(df.dtypes)
df
```

gives

```
id    Int64
dtype: object
    id
0   144123525091332019
1   0
```

BUT

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = [{'id': 144123525091332019}, {'id': None}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,dtype='Int64') # here we are saying that use the int with NA
print(df.dtypes)
df
```

gives the wrong answer

```
id    Int64
dtype: object
    id
0   144123525091332032
1   <NA>
```

as the number gets converted via str->float64 ->Int64 killing the problem in the first place.  Basically, if you can deal with the None differently then things will be better.

Comment: I agree that the core problem is with the None elements. If I can somehow (efficiently) convert the None values to 0 prior to the DataFrame constructor then the issue is probably solved. I'm just not sure how best to do that with the Django ORM.

Comment: You could actually make them all -1 to begin with then change the negative numbers to <NA> in Int64 in pandas later... basically forcing the negative numbers to simulate NaN

Comment: The key question is how best to make the values -1 (or 0 for that matter) prior to constructing the DataFrame. For now we are using the brute force approach with a for loop on the Django QuerySet. I'm hoping there's a better/cleaner way.